# After retracting a solution the Sharepoint 2010 farm displays error

Tags: web-config, farm-solution, retraction

"The DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenuV4' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found."

Comment: Have you retracted a solution with a custom masterpage?

Comment: It didn't seem like it when it was deployed, but probably it had a masterpage

Comment: Well, what you should do is to redploy it and reset all the sites that used the custom masterpage to a default masterpage, or do it from SharePoint Designer / Powershell if you knew what sites that used the retracted masterpage

Comment: I am unable to get into SPD. Would it help if I run psconfig.exe

Comment: No, never run psconfig but after a patch or any other farm modifications that requires it. Can you redeploy the solution to the farm?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you should do is to redploy it and reset all the sites that used the custom masterpage to a default masterpage, or do it from SharePoint Designer / Powershell if you knew what sites that used the retracted masterpage  --  user19952  -- Follow this one.

To switch masterpage custom to default check this link

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=226

once it's done, use powershell to retract solution.

Comment: The retraction was done through PS, but as this was a custom solution (3rd Party), it deleted a number of configuration files which were over written. Something done before my time. The fix in the end was a total restore of the farm. Thanks for the comments